# UTC timestamp conversion to selected timezone timestamp

Tags: javascript, angular

```
this.selectedTimezone="Pacific/Kiritimati"; 
     //this value will come from dropdown
```

this.records = data.body;  //api response

for (var i = 0; i < this.records.length; i++)

{

var d = new Date(this.records[i]['startTimeStamp']);

//it is converting to system timezone date format. I want this one to selected timezone conversion.

var t1 = moment(d).tz(this.selectedTimezone).format();

//2018-11-23T05:30:00+14:00

}

I want this t1 in full date format i.e Friday November 30, 2018 09:00:00

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review the welcome tutorial for SO, and [How to ask...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  What have you tried? It's also unclear, if you're asking for the timestamp to be printed in your local time or a named time zone.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: that is not a UTC date. It looks like a unix epoch

Comment: Convert epoch to other time zone(it will comes from moment js drop down) in java script? for example epoch=1543516200 . I want to convert this epoch to selected timezone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var d1= moment.tz(new Date(this.records[i]['startTimeStamp']), this.selectedTimezone);

var key = d1.year() + "-" + ('0' + (d1.month() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ('0' + (d1.date())).slice(-2);

var timeSlot = ('0' + d1.hour()).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + d1.minutes()).slice(-2);

example:-

var d1= moment.tz(new Date(2543622499000), "Pacific/Kiritimati");

var key = d1.year() + "-" + ('0' + (d1.month() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ('0' + (d1.date())).slice(-2);
    var timeSlot = ('0' + d1.hour()).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + d1.minutes()).slice(-2);

output:-2050-08-09 15:48

Answer (score 0):

See [Moment](https://momentjs.com/) and [Moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).

```js
// This will get "Pacific/Kiritimati" current timezone.
var datetime = moment().tz("Pacific/Kiritimati").format();
var timestamp = moment().tz("Pacific/Kiritimati").valueOf();
console.log(datetime);
console.log(timestamp);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.22.2/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```